# Exact or Numerical solutions of a system of differential equatios

Tags: differential-equations

I need to solve the following system of differential equations:

\begin{align*} 
 x' + 3a \sqrt{ x+ y}x &= -b \sqrt{xy} \\\\
 y' + 3c \sqrt{x+y}y &= b \sqrt{xy}
\end{align*}

where $a$, $b$, $c$ are constant.

I appreciate any help.

Kaveh

Comment: Does the square-root cover x+y in the first equation too?

Comment: Is this homework?  It appears to be so, since this system is easily solved exactly using tools from a first semester ODE course.  If so, try math stack exchange.  If not, maybe you can tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Indeed, I need it to solve another problem in astronomy. It seems that the system in nonlinear but I am not sure about it, maybe if we do some substitutions then easily can be rewrite it in a matrix form 
and solve it; I do not know other possible approaches.  
I have tried stack exchange but have not get any answer yet. 
Yes the square root cover x+y in both equations

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to apologize because I misread your equations, and the technique that I thought applied does not. I actually don't know whether you could solve these equations exactly or not. What you can see, though, is that the qualitative behavior of the solutions depends on the constants $a$, $b$, and $c$, and there are even some cases ($b=0$ and $a=c$) that do seem to be solvable by classical techniques.  Are there certain values (or ranges of values) of the constants that would be most helpful to you?  (Also, I'm not sure why you have retained the $3$s in the coefficients.)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't much of an answer, but I thought that I'd put down a few observations here that you may find helpful.

First of all, if $b=0$, then you have a first integral, in that the ratio $x^{3c}/y^{3a}$ is constant, so you can use this to eliminate, say, $y$ from the first equation, and then the result becomes an autonomous first order equation for $x$ as a function of $t$, which can, in theory, be integrated by quadrature, so let's set this case aside.

When $b\not=0$, you can scale $t$ (the independent variable) so as to make $b=1$, which I'll assume from now on.  Also, I'll replace your $3a$ and $3c$ by $a$ and $c$, respectively, because I don't see what good the $3$s do; they just clutter the formulae.

If you have been trying to do numerics, you may have run into a bit of trouble because the equations as you have written them aren't differentiable, which leads to instabilities in the numerics and nonuniqueness in the solutions.  One way to deal with this is to 'resolve' the singularities by 'unfolding' the domain.  Your equations require that $x{+}y$ and $xy$ both be nonnegative, which can only happen when $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative.  The solutions that have either  $x$ or $y$ vanishing identically are easy to find, so set those aside.  To see what happens to the other solutions, make the substitution $(x,y) = \bigl(4u^2v^2,(u^2-v^2)^2\bigr)$.  The differential equations then become polynomial:
$$
\begin{align}
4u' &=  \phantom{-}v -av(2uv) -cu(u^2{-}v^2),\\\\
4v' &=            -u -au(2uv) +cv(u^2{-}v^2).
\end{align}
\tag1
$$
(A word of caution:  In this parameterization, $\sqrt{xy}=2uv(u^2-v^2)$, which changes sign as one crosses the lines $u=0$, $v=0$, $u=v$ and $u=-v$, so you have to interpret $\sqrt{xy}$ as a signed quantity in your original equations.  Of course, $\sqrt{x{+}y}=u^2+v^2$, so it does not change sign.)

The linear terms on the right hand side of $(1)$ describe the rotation vector field in the $uv$-plane, so the solutions near the origin are either a center or a spiral sink or source.
Hence, the corresponding curves in the $xy$-plane 'bounce' between $x=0$ and $y=0$ an infinite number of times.)

In fact,
$$
\frac{2(u^2+v^2)'}{(u^2{+}v^2)^2} = -c-(a{-}c)\frac{4u^2v^2}{(u^2{+}v^2)^2},
$$
and the right hand side of this expression varies between $-c$ and $-a$, so, unless $a$ and $c$ have opposite signs, a nonzero solution curve always spirals towards (when $a,c>0$) or away from (when $a,c<0$) the origin.

It's also useful to look at things in polar coordinates.  Set 
$$
x=\tfrac12 r^2 (1+\cos\phi)\qquad\text{and}\qquad y = \tfrac12 r^2 (1-\cos\phi).
$$
Then, interpreting $\sqrt{xy}$ as $\tfrac12 r^2\sin\phi$ and $\sqrt{x{+}y}$ as $r$, one computes that
$$
\begin{align}
   r' &=  -\tfrac14\ r^2\bigl( (a{+}c)+(a{-}c)\cos\phi\bigr),\\\\
\phi' &=   b + \tfrac12(a{-}c)\ r\sin\phi.
\end{align}
\tag2
$$
When $a$ and $c$ are positive, this shows that $r$ is strictly decreasing.  In fact, when $r_0>0$ is small, one has $\phi\approx bt$, so integrating in the first equation gives
$$
r \approx 
\left(\frac1{r_0} + \frac{(a{+}c)}4\ t + \frac{(a{-}c)}{4b}\ \sin bt\right)^{-1}.
$$
This gives a reasonably good approximation to the solutions when $r_0 = \sqrt{x_0{+}y_0}$ is small.

Meanwhile, if $a < 0 < c$ and $\sqrt{xy}$ is interpreted to be positive (respectively, when $ c < 0 < a$ and $\sqrt{xy}$ is interpreted to be negative), then there is a fixed point in the first quadrant of the $xy$-plane at 
$$
(x,y) = \left(\frac1{a(a{-}c)},\frac1{c(c{-}a)}\right),
$$
and this gives rise to fixed points in the $uv$-plane, somewhat symmetrically arranged around the origin. Stability analysis of these fixed points will probably tell you something useful.  They appear to be saddles (I haven't checked this for sure), but I have no idea where the separatrices go.

Comment: Many thanks, Robert!
It was quite helpful, for my purpose I needed a solution near the origin. As I understand in general, to solve such system we always can not find a exact solution, we linearize  the system in critical points then solve the system near them. Is that correct?.
by the way in my problem x,y are nonnegative and a,b,c are positive. 

Comment: You're welcome.  Generally speaking, you are right that, when you can't solve the system exactly, the best thing is to try to understand the dynamics and the so-called 'phase portrait'.  However, to linearize near a critical point (and so get the local phase portrait), you need for the equation to be at least differentiable at that critical point, and your equation, as written, is not differentiable near the origin.  That's why it's important to resolve the singularity.  With your condition of positivity on the constants, each solution $(u,v)$ spirals in to the origin as $t$ increases.